# How can I prevent Word 2007 from doing spellcheck for a selection of text?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

How can I prevent Microsoft Word 2007 from doing spellcheck for a selection of text?

Comment: Can you provide more information please. Is this any selection of text, text with a particular format, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Through the Langauage value.

At earlier versions of Word this could be accessed (AFAIR) from the paragraph options.

At Word 2010 this is accessed from the Review tab, Language, "Set Proofing Language" and "do not check spelling or grammar" (after, of course, selecting the text).

Answer (score -1):

Go to :
"Review"---> "spellimg & Grammer" --> "options" ---> "Exceptions for:" (select your document here) ---> mark "Hide spelling errors in this document only"

Comment: -1, OP wants spellcheck disabled only for a selected bit of text, not an entire document.